# react-redux render only when data arraives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a request for data from the server.

In my jsx the main component calls a child component with the props received from that server side request.

Whats happening is that the page is rendered before the data arrives. The problem is that i need this data to build my `divs`.

My child component:

```
render() {
    var append =[];
    var wlStatistics = this.props.wlStatistics;
    ....Some logic(building some html here based on the values on wlStatistics)
     return <div className="col-md-6">
        {append}
    </div>
 }
```

The problem is that page gets rendered before the wlStatistics data arrives, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as your network request will be async. The component's initial render will occur with "initialState" data from your reducer (which appears to be null at this point). This is fine as you can take this opportunity to display a "Loading" component or something to indicate to the user that data is loading from the server.

```
render() {
    const { wlStatistics } = this.props;

    if(!wlStatistics) {
       return (<MyCoolLoader />);
    }

    return (
       <div className="col-md-6">
          {append}
       </div>
    );
}
```

Then the next state update from your action's payload result will re-render the component with it's updated state.

Comment: Second time helping me today, thx alot mark! Actually I knew that about the rendering but you made me double check and i found my bug :]

Answer (score 1):

please  note: network calls are async and react does not wait for the network call to complete. you can either pass default props or show a loading spinner before this.props.wlStatistics is valid. then when data is available your component will show without rerendering example code below

```js
const VideoDetail = ({video}) => {
//check if prop video passed is not null
if(!video){
  //show this if the video request is not done
  return <div>Loading..........</div>;
}
const videoId = video.id.videoId;
const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;
return (
  <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
    <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url}></iframe>
    </div>
    <div className="detail">
      <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
      <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

}
```